# How can I reject the record which not passed condition on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, after-save

I have a Car model which i want to check and discard record before it's saved ,if it not pass the condition from method the code is look like this :

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :wheel_not_zero
  def wheel_not_zero
   false if self.wheel_num == 0 
  end 
end
```

by this solution it'll reject all of car that user send from the form with error and redirect to form again. I want to reject only car which match a condition with out redirect to form again.

I create car record via nested attribute from member model the relation is look like this

`member -> car`    ,so I want to save member record and not matched condition cars record, right now it's reject all records.

thank you for all response :)

Comment: Why not make a validation here instead of a callback?

Comment: sorry I'm already added more information. I  save cars record  via nested attribute ,and it'll reject every record if it's include only one car which matched the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection is not from the model but is from the controller to the view. So if you want to discard the record you should use a validator and in the controller you should manage the exception. 
For example: if the record is invalid you can redirect to the home page or in an other page..

The important thing is keeping in mind that the redirection is separate from the model

Comment: sorry for not clear question, I use a nested attribute for save the record my model relation is look like this 
`member-->car` ,so I save car record via nested attribute on member_controller ,that I can't  handle the redirect directly from member controller.

Comment: http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/ it may be useful for you